# jQuery select box this selected

Tags: jquery

I have a select box and I'm trying to select the option thats chosen from it when its changed. I used to call the element again as you can see in the **before** script but instead of reusing the element id name I tried to select `$(this)` but I can't figure out how to get it to work

**before**

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $('#maptypecontrol>option:selected').val();
});
```

**tried code(failed)**

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $(this+'>option:selected').val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $(this).val();
   alert(maptypecontrolval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `this`

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $(this).val();
    alert(maptypecontrolval);
});
```

BTW you can **also**(Not compulsary but suggestable) use `.on(change(){...})` or `.live(change(){..})`(ofcourse it is **deprecated**) for the On page results.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `$(this).val();` to get the selected value like below.

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function(){
    maptypecontrolval = $('option:selected', this).val();
    console.log(maptypecontrolval);
});
```

This will give you the value of the option selected on dropdown `change` event, which you can check in the browser console.

[**Fiddle Demo #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxJzg/)

---

or you can just do this:

```
$('#maptypecontrol').change(function () {
    maptypecontrolval = this.value;
    console.log(maptypecontrolval);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxJzg/1/)